# Is it possible to receive data from nifi and add that data to the data received from kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

Is it possible to receive data from nifi and add that data to the data received from kafka?

I tried to input the data and view the data. But I do not know how to get that data. Do you get the stacked data in the queue? Do you import data stored in a specific directory?

First, I wonder if this is possible in nifi.
Once you have entered certain data, hold it for a while. (For example, 'testtext')
When you receive certain data from kafka, you add the data you have for a while to the back. (For example, if you receive kafka data, the result should be 'kafka data testtext'.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **`MergeContent`** processor.

- Use `Max Bin Age` property value(5 mins..etc) to force merge the flowfiles.
- Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/137961/how-to-merge-flowfiles-in-nifi.html) and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/64337/apache-nifi-merge-content.html) links for configuring/usage of mergecontent processor.